# transfer documents to vector space representation, how to generate the dictionary?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I have large amount of unstructured text documents, for each document, I want a vector space representation, so that it is easy for me to classify the documents into clusters and do semantic nature analysis. Many way to transfer documents to vector space, like bag-of-words (BOW) model,  Latent Semantic Analysis (LSA), n gram model,etc. But I think all of them need a Dictionary for the keywords.(not sure) But if there is no query, how to generate the Dictionary for a large amount of documents?(1 million) How to determine important words in a document?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple frequency model to determine which words are important and need to be included in your dictionary or lexicon. This model assumes that words with a lower total count (lower than some threshold) are unimportant and can be safely excluded.

You can start with a very large dictionary by using a simple frequency model and then use feature selection methods like information gain, mutual information, chi-squared, etc to further reduce the size of your lexicon (see "A comparative study on feature selection in text categorization" by Yang and Pedersen for more information on feature selection methods).